# how to integrate power bi with angular, error : Cannot find module 'powerbi-client-angular' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, npm, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Error occuring at : import { PowerBIEmbedModule } from "powerbi-client-angular";
error : Cannot find module 'powerbi-client-angular' or its corresponding type declarations

```
`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';import { AppComponent } from './app.component';import { NgxPowerBiModule} from 'ngx-powerbi';import * as pbi from 'powerbi-client';import { PowerBIEmbedModule } from "powerbi-client-angular";
```

```
@NgModule({declarations: [AppComponent],imports: [BrowserModule,AppRoutingModule,NgxPowerBiModule,NgxPowerBiModule,
```

```
],providers: [],bootstrap: [AppComponent]})export class AppModule { }`
```

I have following document to apply power bi in my app, but it is giving me error.

I have  tried to run :

> >npm install ngrx-powerbi
>
> \>npm install powerbi-client
>
> \>npm install --save powerbi-client
>
> \>npm i angular-powerbi-report

I don't know much about power bi, and i am also new to angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command to install [powerbi-client-angular-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-angular) library

```
npm i powerbi-client-angular
```

You can refer to demo of the [powerbi-client-angular-github](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-angular) wrapper.